# How to keep both bluetooth keyboard and virtual keyboard in ios

Tags: ios, keyboard, bluetooth

I write an app work with bluetooth barcode scanner, but when it connected, it prevent the virtual keyboard popup, I can't input any text.
I got 2 solutions in my mind:
1. Force show virtual keyboard even if bluetooth keyboard connected.
2. Control the system do not treat the scanner as input device but still accept it's inputs.
But I cannot do neither of them, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. On the iPad I was able to double click the barcode gun trigger and that prompted the virtual keyboard. However, this did NOT work on Android.

I'm using this barcode scanner: http://www.cilico.us/product/1d-laser-barcode-scanner.html

=]

Comment: on Huawei Android phone, there is "show virtual keyboard" function to keep virtual keyboard on screen when a physical keyboard is connected

Answer (score 2):

I have added details on how to show both bluetooth keyboard(using HID profile) and device virtual keyboard here [I want to force keyboard on with bluetooth device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418790/i-want-to-force-keyboard-on-with-bluetooth-device) Please check if it helps.