# I want to force keyboard on with bluetooth device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, keyboard

I have a bluetooth barcode device.
If connect the bluetooth device to the iPhone, I can't write anything using iPhone keyboard.
you already know that IPhone keyboard does not show on, because the bluetooth device is recognized keyboard.

But!!! I have to write something by keyboard into the textbox while iphone connect with bluetooth device.

Please Let me know how to do that! :)
Thanks~

Comment: did you find any solution? Same problem here!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can show device virtual keyboard even when a bluetooth keyboard is connected. We need to use `inputAccessoryView` for that.

We need to add below code in app delegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *inputAccessoryView;
```

add below notifications in - `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method in **delegate.m**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldBegan:) name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
```

This will call below method when we focus on a `textField`.

```
//This function responds to all `textFieldBegan` editing
// we need to add an accessory view and use that to force the keyboards frame
// this way the keyboard appears when the bluetooth keyboard is attached.
-(void) textFieldBegan: (NSNotification *) theNotification
{

        UITextField *theTextField = [theNotification object];

        if (!inputAccessoryView) {
            inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
            [inputAccessoryView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        }

        theTextField.inputAccessoryView = inputAccessoryView;

        [self performSelector:@selector(forceKeyboard) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

and the code for "forceKeyboard" is,

```
-(void) forceKeyboard
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    inputAccessoryView.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 420, screenHeight, 352);

}
```

This works fine for us. We use a hidden text field for getting input from bluetooth keyboard and for all other text fields we use device virtual keyboard which is displayed using `inputAccessoryView`.

Please let me know if this helps and if you need any more details.

Comment: this doesn't work on iOS8 & 9  , is there any alternative solution ?

Comment: Anybody found a solution to this?

Comment: @AndyM , does it show any error/warning when you implement the above code in iOS 8/9 ?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution yet? iOS 10 and still the same problem. Now it only shows the inputAccessoryView. I thought about set up a button to force the keyboard to show up, but I don't know how or if it's even possible

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView Subclass follow UIKeyInput protocol.

```
@interface SomeInputView : UIView <UIKeyInput> {
```

and in implementation file (.m)

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

-(void)insertText:(NSString *)text {
    //Some text entered by user
}

-(void)deleteBackward {
    //Delete key pressed
}
```

Whenever you want to show Keyboard just do

```
[myInputView becomeFirstResponder];
```